# splunk check if message contains certain string

Tags: java, devops, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

In Splunk search query how to check if log message has a text or not?

**Log message:**

```
message:     2018-09-21T07:15:28,458+0000 comp=hub-lora-ingestor-0 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  com.nsc.iot.hono.receiver.HonoReceiver - Connected successfully, creating telemetry consumer ...
```

and I want to check if message contains **"Connected successfully, creating telemetry consumer ..."** and based on this want to assign 1 or 0 to a variable

**Splunk search Query**

```
(index="05c48b55-c9aa-4743-aa4b-c0ec618691dd" ("Retry connecting in 1000ms ..." OR "Connect or create consumer failed with exception" OR "Connected successfully, creating telemetry consumer ...")) 
| rex field=_raw ^(?:[^ \n]* ){7}(?P<success_status_message>\w+\s+\w+,\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)"
| timechart count as status | eval status=if(isnull(success_status_message), 0, 1)
```

success_status_message is always null

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: @RichG no it's not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the problem is the regex string, which doesn't match the sample data. Another problem is the unneeded `timechart` command, which filters out the 'success_status_message' field.  Try this search:

```
(index="05c48b55-c9aa-4743-aa4b-c0ec618691dd" ("Retry connecting in 1000ms ..." OR "Connect or create consumer failed with exception" OR "Connected successfully, creating telemetry consumer ..."))
| rex "\s-\s(?P<success_status_message>.*)" 
| eval status=if(match(success_status_message, "Connected successfully, creating telemetry consumer"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: If I don't use the timechart how can I visualize 1 and 0 on a chart?

Comment: Add your chart or timechart command *after* the `eval`.  `... | timechart count by status`

Comment: thanks.. this was a big help. I used | timechart latest(status) as status span=10m to achieve my requirement